# No such file or directory on binary which exists

Tags: nixos

I'm trying to run a binary from the ghidra suite. (Actually, I'm running ghidra itself, but it's failing to run the binary internally).

```
[nix-shell:~]$ ./ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/os/linux64/decompile 
bash: ./ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/os/linux64/decompile: No such file or directory
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is: I read that missing libs can cause this, and `ldd` reported that libstdc++.so.6 was missing. After much mucking about getting libstdc++.so.6 to be picked up (nix seems to make life difficult there), I'm greeted with the same error:

```
[nix-shell:~]$ ./ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/os/linux64/decompile 
bash: ./ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/os/linux64/decompile: No such file or directory

[nix-shell:~]$ ldd ./ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/os/linux64/decompile 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffd9293000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /nix/store/f09zmq3sqiy0dnx8g4f1arngkjd4kih7-gcc-7.4.0-lib/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f20ca795000)
        libm.so.6 => /nix/store/h0p0h3rh1q4i2yavzm3yqi716s9yaj2f-glibc-2.27/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f20ca5ff000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /nix/store/f09zmq3sqiy0dnx8g4f1arngkjd4kih7-gcc-7.4.0-lib/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f20ca5e6000)
        libc.so.6 => /nix/store/h0p0h3rh1q4i2yavzm3yqi716s9yaj2f-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f20ca430000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /nix/store/h0p0h3rh1q4i2yavzm3yqi716s9yaj2f-glibc-2.27/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f20ca921000)
```

Does anyone have any more ideas? A little more info:

```
[nix-shell:~]$ file ./ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/os/linux64/decompile 
./ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/os/linux64/decompile: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=bd3c148954c7800224c513a9d91ce61e50cb1a03, not stripped
```

Comment: Verify that all the libraries in the ldd listing actually exist? In particular, that none of them are dangling symlinks?

Comment: Thanks - should have thought of that. They all seem to exist.

Comment: Nixpkgs master seems to have a ghidra-bin derivation: `nix-shell -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/master.tar.gz -p ghidra-bin`

Comment: I needed to add extensions, so couldn't use the nix version. I ended up solving this by copying the nix version out of the store and setting write permissions, instead of trying to use the one downloaded from ghidra's website. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the file command output `interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` seems to be wrong.
maybe try this to make the executable work:

```
patchelf --set-interpreter $(patchelf --print-interpreter `which cp`) \
  ./ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/os/linux64/decompile
```

Comment: see https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Packaging/Binaries -> `autoPatchelfHook` or `patchelf --set-interpreter "$(cat $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker)" binaryfile` or [steam-run](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Steam#steam-run)